# NSDataDetector do not find .io website

Tags: swift, nsdatadetector

It is not so important but if I use NSDataDetector like [here](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) and use it for weblink, I can show all website with .com, .us or even .ca but not for .io
If I use http://website.io it is working but if the text is website.io it is not working.

Does someone have a workaround to make it work ?

Sample code working in Playground if you need:

```
var string = "website.io is not ok but website.com is ok"
var error: NSError?
let detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: &error)
detector?.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, (string as NSString).length)) { (result, flags, _) in
    println(result)
    println(flags)
}
```

Output is website.com {25,11}

Missing website.io {0, 10}

**Edit:**

It is not written on wiki english but on my language, there is some "complacency" domain as .ad .am .cd .co .io .me .mu .nu .tv .je .sr

I just try and only .me works. Is it an Apple limitation for this "still" top-level domains ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to file a bug with Apple. However I think it is intentionally omitted because "io" means I in Italian and some people fail to include a space after a dot when finishing a sentence. So if .io got added you'd detect "buon giorno.io non lo so" as a link (it's not). Including http:// or another marker like <> will force the detection.

Comment: I didn't think in this way, but .je is the same for french people. So you're maybe right and as it is not so important, I won't report it as a bug, I just wanted to know if I am missing something or didn't use it well. Thanks.

Comment: I've reported a bug to Apple. They said that they only check for popular country extensions, like uk, fr, de, etc., because checking for every ccTLD would cause those false positive explained by Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

Some TLDs aren't detected by `NSDataDetector`, for undisclosed reasons (although Mr. Deniau's guess seems plausible.)

A common workaround is to use [twitter-text-objc](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/objc), which will detect all TLDs. Call `[TwitterText URLsInText:]` to obtain an array of matching URLs. You can use the `range` returned by these to create links, etc.

Comment: I didn't want to use a library just for that, but look like it will fit latin link but also cyrilic, arabic and all other alphabet. Thank you.